# String to datetime in update query

Tags: sql, date, datetime, phpmyadmin

I already have a successful update query that joins tables to enter the date from the PROJECT_CLEAN table into the TABLE_PROGRESS table to show the most recent record for each evaluation unit (EU), but it keeps the date-time as a string, which I can't really do any analysis with.

I need to adjust this update query slightly to take the string version from the PROJECT_CLEAN table ("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS") and convert it to datetime (YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS) in the TABLE_PROGRESS table. Here is the existing query:

```
UPDATE IGNORE TABLE_PROGRESS AS prog
JOIN (SELECT cast(EU AS UNSIGNED) AS eu, MAX(START_TIME) AS max, CLUSTER_COMPLETE AS complete FROM `PROJECT_CLEAN` GROUP BY EU) AS project
ON prog.EUID = project.EU
SET prog.Date_Completed = project.max
WHERE project.complete>0;
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Nevermind- I figured it out. I just had to clear out the TABLE_PROGRESS table and make sure the date fields had the right format... and then the same query still worked and now the dates are no longer strings

Comment: So the lesson is, make sure the field in the target table has correct data-type when you run an update query.  @beck777, suggest you either (a) provide the answer as an answer and accept it or (b) delete the whole post.  Or I'll send it to Community Wiki in a day or two.  It's basic enough to be trivial, prompting some to declare it a "typo or isolated error" post; but perhaps it will help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I just had to clear out the TABLE_PROGRESS table and make sure the date fields had the right format... and then the same query still worked and now the dates are no longer strings

– beck777 May 6 at 16:49